# How can I get an X509Certificate2 object for an authenticated user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I'm a bit out of my depth here so bear with me if I say/ask/do something idiotic.

Anyways, I have a dll that I need to use for a project of mine. Essentially, this dll is my interface to another service I need to use. I don't own the dll so I can't change it's interface/code at all, and the interface to the underlying service is unknown (expect by using its SDK dll obviously). One of the functions I need to use from this sdk requires me to provide either the user's name & password in plain `String` format, in `String` and `SecureString` formats, or just provide an `X509Certificate2` object.

My website is currently configured to use windows authentication. What I would like to do is be able to call into this dll without asking for the user's password (seeing as they already had to enter it in order to access the site). I am assuming that there is a snowball's chance in hell that I have access to the user's password itself as either a `String` or `SecureString`, but it looked like I could construct the x509 certificate object doing something like this:

```
var x509 = new X509Certificate2(Request.ClientCertificate.Certificate);
```

Unfortunately, it appears like `Request.ClientCertificate.Certificate` is always empty for whatever reason.

Is there some other way that I can access this information? If I have sufficient information to impersonate the user (via `HttpContext.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Impersonate()`), then should I not have enough information to construct a `X509Certificate2` object for this user as well? If not, what would I need to do to get the client certificate populated in the request?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!